# Distorted Screen / wrong aspect ratio when mirror 2 screens with different native resolutions

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Hi I have 2 screens with the native resolution of

1920 x 1080 16:9 and

1920 x 1200 16:10

When I mirror the display with the resolution of 1920 x 1080 16:9 in Windows then I get a black bars on top and bottom of my 16:10 and the resolution is fine and works normal.

If I try to do the same thing on ubuntu there are no black bars on top and bottom. The screen is just completely filled but distorted.

Basically it fills the 16:9 resolution over the 16:10 screen and distorts it by doing that.

I am using GNOME on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Any solution?

Comment: I dont get it.  What are you expecting?  It has to fill in something.  What dopes it matter, what it is?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta
No it hasnt? Windows is able to have a 16:9 aspect ratio on a 16:10 screen by having black bars at the top and bottom. 
My Ubuntu just distorts the whole screen which makes it obviously unusable.